# Which packages must i use to draw frame around a page like this?

Tags: frame-title, draw

i want to draw frame like this picture below.

Which packages can i use for it?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[20pt]{14pt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\sloppy
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

[image: Frame]

Comment: `\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}`.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253354/how-to-interpret-the-page-layout-in-latex-using-layout-package for list of relevant LaTeX page dimensions.

Comment: First time I read about `pass` option.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example. The best solution may depend on your class and which packages, if any, you are using to configure page layout.

Comment: @Sigur `pass` is great when one wants not to muck with the default geometry of a class, but have access to things like `showframe` and the ability to *subsequently* alter page geometry is very useful.  See, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253354/how-to-interpret-the-page-layout-in-latex-using-layout-package

Comment: Cfr,I don't understand what you mean in this case by minimal example.Because i am a beginner with LaTeX, i am totally don't understand which packages or  commands must i use.So,i think, you ask me about my preamble, don't you?

Comment: If you are already using the `geometry` package, as your updated MWE reveals, just add `showframe`, but not `pass` as an option.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes, if i add \geometry{showframe} in the preamble, then i got two lines on top and two on the right, except  frame.

Comment: Do you really want to use `\sloppy` for the whole document? Though I guess this a poster or something given the font size?

Comment: It is true that `showframe` not only shows the text area, but also the place where headers, footers, and margin notes will be placed.  If you **only** want the single box around the available text area, the approach would have to be a little different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, I suspected the OP wanted a simple `showframe`.  Then, I revised my understanding that the OP wanted a `showframe`, but only around the text area (not headers, footers, or marginnote area).

Finally, I concluded, based on the OP's MWE, that the frame's dimensions to be created were not a precise match of the text area.  Thus, here, I use `everypage` to place a frame on the particular page of invocation, but that can be made on everypage with a 1-word change.

I use my `\atxy` macro to place the upper left of the frame at 20mm right and 5mm down from the upper left corner.  I make the frame of the right size as follows: `\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-25mm}{0pt}\rule[-\dimexpr\paperheight-8mm]{0pt}{\dimexpr\paperheight-8mm}` and place an `\fbox` around it with `\fboxsep` set equal to `-\fboxrule`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[20pt]{14pt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm%
%  ,showframe%
]{geometry}
\sloppy
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{% CHANGE \AddThispageHook to \AddEverypageHook IF NEEDED
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{red}{#3}}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\newcommand\textframe{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule%
  \color{red}\fbox{\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-25mm}{0pt}%
  \rule[-\dimexpr\paperheight-8mm]{0pt}{\dimexpr\paperheight-8mm}}}
\begin{document}
\atxy{20mm}{5mm}{\textframe}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can compare this to the `showframe` layout by uncommenting the `showframe` line from the MWE.

[image]